# DataGridView columns stop working correctly after clearing data and repopulating columns

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset, datasource

In my first attempt at using DataGridView in a useful application, I am happy to say that I was able to come across many useful posts that helped me build a rudimentary & functional app. My DataGridView is currently a fixed 4 column grid that is querying data from a MySQL database. Column 4 must be a hyperlink type of column. When I execute the following code the first time, via a button, the results are exactly what I expect and I am full of joy:

[image: Good Execution]

The get button code is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_GetData.Click
    cnString = "datasource=" + ip + ";username=" + username + ";password=" + password + ";database=" + database_name + ""
    sqlQRY = "Select * from " + table_name + " WHERE Batch =" + txt_PalletNo.Text + ""

    If txt_PalletNo.Text = "*" Then
        sqlQRY = "Select * from " + table_name + ""
    Else
        sqlQRY = "Select * from " + table_name + " WHERE Batch =" + txt_PalletNo.Text + ""
    End If

    conn = New MySqlConnection(cnString)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlQRY, conn)
        Dim cb As MySqlCommandBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Fill(ds, "" + table_name + "") 
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "" + table_name + "" 
        txt_qty.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "" + table_name + ""

    Catch ex As Common.DbException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        txt_PalletNo.Clear()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

However if I use a button to clear the grid and request a new set of data, the column properties seem to change, the headers change and column 4 seems to be switched to a normal text column as shown here:

[image: Bad execution]

The clear button code is:

```
Private Sub btn_Clear_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Clear.Click
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    ds.Clear()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear() 'I also tried Columns.Clear() Here
    txt_PalletNo.Clear()
    txt_qty.Clear()
End Sub
```

I need help understanding what happens when I run the function that populates the grid a second time or third time. I thought clearing the dataset and running the function again would yield the same column properties every time. To be humble and honest this is my first attempt at using DataGridView so my knowledge is very limited. I am hoping it is a simple property that I have not selected correctly.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this should be there ds.Clear()

Comment: From these symptoms I would say that you have defined your columns using the Designer and after Clear you wipe away every setting made in designer. By the way, why you concatenate your table_name variable with empty strings?

Comment: Try adding `DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()` to your load routine.

Comment: @Claudius - I tried to remove ds.Clear() before. As an example if I GET pallet 5511 the grid populates with the relevant data. In this example 4 records get returned. If I clear the grid and do a GET for the same pallet 5511 then 8 records get returned erroneously. It basically appends every subsequent GET. If I GET pallet 3322 it will append those 4 records to the 8 from 5511. The CLEAR may clear the visible grid; it simply returns on the next iteration of the GET. I don't mind if each GET appends to the previous if I don't clear the grid. However if I explicitly clear I want to start fresh.

Comment: @Steve - You are 100% correct. Since I am not too familiar with DataViewGrid I used some video tutorials to get as far as I did with the designer. I am not too keen on how to programatically achieve what the designer does for me in a few clicks. Is there a way to enforce the column properties as permanent? As for the "" empty strings - I believe this is a bad habit I have picked up to make certain things pop on the screen and it offers easy insertion points for modifying strings. I don't really have an explanation why I continue. I have just seen it multiple times on various sample code.

Comment: @rheitzman - I added 'DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()' to 'frm_Load' and it did not change my problematic behavior. In fact all it did was shrink the columns. The first GET was hyper-linked as expected; the second GET was faulty.

Comment: Probably just removing the _DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()_ could help a lot. In any case the [DataGridView page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN is your starting point to learn how to work with this fairly complex control. From there you could navigate to the [DataGridViewColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) another focal point around your problem

Comment: @dejan87 - If i set 'ds = Nothing' the first GET works properly. The second GET throws exception 'da.Fill(ds, "" + table_name + "")'<---'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dataSet'.

Comment: @generatorlabs You need to create new instance . If u need to clear ds  create new instance  ds = new dataSet and fill it again

Comment: @dejan87 -You hit the nail on the head! I observed that the `Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet` is at the top of the `Public Class frm_` and was not called again. By placing another dataset line withing the CLEAR Button I can cause controlled results. I basically created an sql query that would return no records, created a new dataset instance and used the same code as the GET button to populate the grid with nothing. This was the only way the columns would stay formatted as before. You are a life saver. **THANK YOU** I am new to the forum. I don't think I can mark as answer yet. Is that true?

Comment: @generatorlabs I answered you, now you can mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use **ds.clear** 
You need to create new instance. If u need to clear ds create new instance and fill it again

```
  ds = new dataSet
```